# Chrome and Firefox responsive mode VS Phone responsive mode

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Can someone explain to me why in Chrome responsive mode my web page looks good, and on the mobile it looks differently that I don't like.

And yes I used:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in my HTML.

[Chrome responsive mode:] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIkBo.png)

[Phone responsive mode:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgRxi.jpg)

This my CSS that im using to make my website responsive:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
  
  html,
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
  }

  body {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 195);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  #video-background {
    display: none;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .message-top {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    top: 15vh;
    font-family: 'San Francisco';
    font-weight: bolder;
    left: 22vh;
  }

  .coming_soon {
    top: 25vh;
  }

  .message-bottom {
    display: none;
  }

  #analog-clock {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50vh;
    left: 47%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vw;
    opacity: initial;
  }

  #clock-dial {
    width: 70vw;
    height: 70vw;
  }

  #hour-hand {
    width: 0.18vh;
    height: 20%;
    top: 28%;
    left: 49.5%;
  }

  #sec-hand {
    width: 0.5%;
    height: 30%;
    top: 16.5%;
    left: 49%;
  }

  .logo-bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: -5%;
    left: -5%;
  }

  .logo-bg img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vh;
    top: -3%;
    left: -3%;
  }

  #social-sidebar {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .scroll-button {
    top: 80%;
    max-width: min-content;
  }

  .bg-below-video {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-width: auto;
    min-height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  #home-button {
    top: -45vh !important;
    position: relative;
    right: -24vh;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    bottom: 500%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: black;
  }

  #subscribe-button-x {
    top: -45vh !important;
    position: relative;
    right: -24vh;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    bottom: 500%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: black;
  }

  #subscribe-button-x {
    padding: initial;
    background-color: initial;
    text-decoration: initial;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: initial;
  }

  #home-button:hover,
  #subscribe-button-x:hover {
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: DevTools is just a simulation of mobile devices. It can't truly simulate an iPhone. So it's always a good idea to check how it actually looks on the devices that you care about (like you did). I don't think there's any bug or issue here. It's just an instance where the DevTools simulation doesn't reflect reality 100%. I suggest using a device simulator of some sort.

Comment: Amazing, thanks @Kameron I just found a chrome extension that is working perfectly.

Comment: can you be more specific about what it means to look different?